# Certificate Error - Website calling Apex web service

Tags: apex, webservices, ssl

I have an Apex class exposed as a web service. When our Cold Fusion based website calls this service, they get the following error:

Error: I/O Exception: Name in certificate 'na14.salesForce.com' does not match host name 'na14-api.salesForce.com'

It seems to me that SF has a certificate for na14.salesforce.com but not na14-api.salesforce.com. However the Sandbox had a certificate for cs9-api.salesforce.com and for cs9.salesforce.com

I have more details here:
http://www.evernote.com/shard/s80/sh/6e58fc8a-10f4-4b26-a4b9-a623947475fa/51a866d1a1e87bacb7a69962063747f1

Has anyone ran into this problem before?

Do I need to do something with Setup | Security Controls | Certificate and Key Management? I haven't used that before and the documentation seems to refer to using that when calling out to an external web service where I am having someone call my service.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried this,

1. revise the WSDL file, like
   location="https://na14.salesforce.com/services/Soap/class/AttendeeTrackerClass"
2. deploy the updated WSDL file in your Website again.
3. call the Apex WS from your Website

I guess you can call the Apex WS from na14.salesforce.com directly, and let Salesforce to transfer it to na14-api.salesForce.com.